# Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool -Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

**Problem: Visual Studio 2013 and ASP.NET Web Configuration Tool**

I wanted to make fast roles etc. I tried enable it using this article: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/08/19/asp-net-web-configuration-tool-missing-in-visual-studio-2013.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments .

I can enter the configuration tool, I added 2 roles & users but than when I want to log in in my website in VS already I have the following mistake:

[image]

In addition, even though my web site is hold in the "C:\Aspnet\ WebSite4-20150614_m10z1" I realize that new app_data folder appeared automatically (second already) with the base aspnetdb - this time in the following path (in "C:\Aspnet"). One level upper.

**what I did already:**

**x IIS Express**
iisexpress.exe /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
*information: registration completed*

**x Developer Command Promopt for VS2013**
aspnet_regsql -A all -C "Data Source= WIN-G6HBJHSJ5B3\SQLEXPRESS; Integrated Security=True; User Instance=True" -d "C:\Aspnet\WebSite4-20150614_m10z1\App_Data\AdventureWorksLT2008_Data.mdf"

**Attachments:**
**x web config:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AdventureWorksLT2008_DataConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AdventureWorksLT2008_Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

      <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomizedRoleProvider">
        <providers>
          <add name="CustomizedRoleProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
            applicationName="AdventureWorks"
            connectionStringName="AdventureWorksLT2008_DataConnectionString"/>
      </providers>
      </roleManager>

    <membership defaultProvider="CustomizedMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="CustomizedMembershipProvider"
             type="system.Web.Security.SqlmembershipProvider"
             applicationName="AdventureWorks"
             connectionStringName="AdventureWorksLT2008_DataConnectionString"/>   
      </providers>  

    </membership>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="Zaloguj.aspx" />
    </authentication>

    <authorization>
      <allow roles="Administrator"/>
    </authorization>

  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**x administration tool**
In the "Web Site Administration Tool" in the Application I have emptiness after the mark "/" . This is how it looks "Application: /" 
[image]

**Suspicious:**
connection to ASPNETDB & right configuration of aspnet_regsql

Answer (score -1):

check the procedure proper name that you have implemented in code behind this is not same or it can't get the procedure name

Comment: it is the same, it simply can not get the procedure name :(